# Does anybody can help me why i cannot open my local files in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Does anybody can help me why i cannot open my local files in google colab

Could not fetch resource at : 403 Forbidden
FetchError: Could not fetch resource at : 403 Forbidden

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should mount your files in colab first

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

then you can access your file..

```
example = '/content/drive/My Drive/txt_example.txt'
```